# Spring Boot @CrossOrigin annotation not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring 2.6.6 and Reactjs for frontend. I have a POST endpoint exposed using a rest controller but is is giving CORS error when api is called

Below is the rest controller

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RequestMapping("/image")
public class ImageUpload {
    
    @Autowired
    private ExtractData extractData;
    
    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    @PostMapping("/extract")
    public Map<String, ArrayList<String>> upload(
            @RequestParam(value = "image") MultipartFile image,
            @RequestParam(value = "selectedOptions") String selectedOptions
    ) throws IOException, TesseractException {
        Map<String, Boolean> selectedOptionsMap = gson.fromJson(selectedOptions, Map.class);
        byte[] imageData = image.getBytes();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
        try {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage =  ImageIO.read(bais);
            Map<String, ArrayList<String>> resultSet = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
            resultSet = extractData.extractData(selectedOptionsMap, bufferedImage);
            return resultSet;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Also implemented WebMvcConfigurer as follows but this also didn't work:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/image/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

My security configuration class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Request headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 110239
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryX8BGweBFqsM2R7hy
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 03 Jul 2022 13:37:57 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Also adding CORS filter implementation did not work

Comment: Obviously the CORS headers are missing in the response. Did you try to allow CORS in the Spring Security's configuration via `http.cors()`?

Comment: That worked! I just had to add http.cors() and it started working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing http.cors() in the security configuration
Changing the configure method as follows solved the problem

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```